# switch with preg_match return true if string is empty

Tags: php, preg-match, switch-statement

i've a problem with a switch and a preg_match case
my code is like this

```
switch( $WORD ){

    case ( preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD , $ID )  ? true : false ):
        echo "valid ". $ID ." test -> " .preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD );
    break;

    default:
        echo $WORD;
    break;
}
```

these code work well with

```
$WORD = "TEST";        print => TEST
$WORD = "TEST-1";      print => valid 1 test -> 1
$WORD = "TEST-2552";   print => valid 2552 test -> 1
$WORD = "343";         print => valid 343 test -> 1
```

but if `$WORD` is null or `$WORD = ""` the case is true too and it print

```
$WORD = "";      print => valid  test -> 0
```

how i can fix it?
i've tried with

```
case ( ( preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD , $ID ) == 1 )  ? true : false ):
```

but dosne't work

Comment: i'm using switch because i have alot of cases.. but i didn't posted in the code here because it was too long and useles
only one case have that preg_match

Comment: Good question don't know why every one who can not answer complains here and says use `if`. It's funny really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've resolved it with a simple trick so if some one have the same problem that is a way to resolve it ... ( at the moment i don't know if exist a better way )

Just before the case with `preg_match` add a case like `case "":`

```
switch( $WORD ){

    default:
    case "":
        // call a function
    break;

    case preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i", $WORD, $ID ) ? true : false:
        echo "valid and id is: ". $ID ;
    break;

    // all other common cases
    case "home":
    case "dog":
    case "cat":
    case "fish":
        // call a function
    break;

    case "bull":
    case "shark":
    case "somethingelse":
        // call a function
    break;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `switch` was meant to be used and I'm not even sure if it could work this way. The whole idea of `switch` is to have a short notation for chained `if`-statements.

```
if ($foo == 1) { ... }
else if ($foo == 2) { ... }
else if ($foo == 3) { ... }
else { ... }
```

becomes

```
switch ($foo) {
   case 1: ... break;
   case 2: ... break;
   case 3: ... break;
   default: ...
}
```

Especially when having a very complex condition in `$foo` you can save a lot of duplicated code. In your case using `switch` does not really make a lot of sense. Just go with `if` and you are good to go:

```
if (preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD , $ID )) {
    echo "valid ". $ID ." test -> " .preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD );
} else {
    echo $WORD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i cant understand why you are using switch to select a boolean

when $WORD is "" ,
switch($WORD) equals switch(false)

then your problem happens

why not

```
if(preg_match("/^(?:.+-)?(\d+?)$/i",  $WORD , $ID )){
echo "valid ";
}else{
echo $WORD;
}
```